JPA CriteriaQuery: using same expression in select and orderBy
I tried to write belowed SQL with CriteriaAPI in Hibernate 6.2.6:
select foo.id,
       foo.bar,
       bar.name
from foo
left join bar on bar.code = foo.bar
order by bar.name;

This is my kotlin code:
val builder = em.criteriaBuilder
val query = builder.createQuery(Any::class.java)
val root = query.from(Foo::class.java)
val sortJoin = root.join<Foo, Bar>("bar", JoinType.LEFT).get<Expression<*>>("name")
query.multiselect(root, sortJoin)
query.orderBy(builder.asc(sortJoin))

Hibernate produced result looks like:
select
        s1_0.id,
        s1_0.bar,
        s2_0.name 
    from
        foo s1_0 
    left join
        bar s2_0 
            on s2_0.code=s1_0.bar 
    order by
        20

I can't understand, why did expression become a constant?
If I don't use bar.name in multiselect, orderBy clause is well, but YDB need it in the select.
How can I reuse expression in orderBy?
I tried to use alias, but the result is same too.
Separate expressions didn't help too
val builder = em.criteriaBuilder
val query = builder.createQuery(Any::class.java)
val root = query.from(Foo::class.java)
val sortJoin = root.join<Foo, Bar>("bar", JoinType.LEFT).get<Expression<*>>("name")
query.multiselect(root, root.get<Path<*>>("bar").get<Expression<*>>("name"))
query.orderBy(builder.asc(sortJoin))

because every expression creates own join
select
        s1_0.id,
        s1_0.bar,
        s3_0.name 
    from
        foo s1_0 
    left join
        bar s2_0 
            on s2_0.code=s1_0.bar 
    join
        bar s3_0 
            on s3_0.code=s1_0.bar 
    order by
        s2_0.name

UPDATE:
One way, I found, is to use a whole join in multiselect like this
val builder = em.criteriaBuilder
val query = builder.createQuery(Any::class.java)
val root = query.from(Foo::class.java)
// Only join
val sortJoin = root.join<Foo, Bar>("bar", JoinType.LEFT)
query.multiselect(root, sortJoin)
// Order by the field from join
query.orderBy(builder.asc(sortJoin.get<Expression<*>>("name")))

This is correct, but it seems a little rebundant to include extra fields in select clause
